# Drop down box to be populated by data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in my team folder and I am having trouble making a drop down box in it that has all the league name that was already created.

```
<select style="width: 193px" type="text">
  <%= f.collection_select :leagues_id, @leagues, :id, :league_name, :prompt => true %>
</select>
```

This is so far what I got. I am also not sure if I used the collection_select correctly. :(

Somebody please help me. I'm new in rails. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is the problem you have currently? Do you get any error?

Comment: yes. it says undefined method `leagues_id' for #<Team:0x8f35c80>

Comment: Try changing it to `league_id`

Comment: it should be `league_id`

Comment: it's still an error. undefined method `league_id' for #<Team:0x93485e8>

Comment: Do you have `league_id` field in team table? Can you show relation between team and leagues?

Comment: I created a new field in my team table name league_name that is a foreign key to the league table. I already changed it to league_name, but still an error.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `teams` (
 `teams_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 `team_name` varchar,
 `team_color` varchar,
 `division` varchar,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `league_name` INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY(`league_name`) REFERENCES `leagues`(`leagues_id`)
);

This is what I have in my database

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `@leagues` variable is populated correctly, you could do something like this:

```
<select style="width: 193px" type="text">
  <%= f.select :leagues_id, options_for_select( @leagues.map { |league| 
    [ league.name, league.id ]}), prompt: true %>
</select>
```

Also, the first argument `:leagues_id` must be the attribute name in your `Team` model. Make sure it is spelled correctly, because normally it comes in singular, such as `:league_id`.

Comment: what should I put as an argument after the @leagues?

Comment: Take a loot at the docs for select_tag
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag
the 1st argument is the attribute name and the 2nd one are the options